# Poisson distribution function or not

Tags: probability-theory

I am confused in identifying whether this problem belongs to Poisson distribution or else. I need your help to solve this problem, thanks.

A radar gauges the speed of cars on a busy road for 5 minutes. According to previous experience, the probability that there will be a car exceeding the speed limit is the same as of all cars abiding the speed limit. What's the probability of exactly 3 cars exceeding the speed limit?

Comment: You need to know the average number of cars traveling the road.  The distribution is most likely Poisson.

Comment: How we can find the average number of cars traveling the road,@herb steinberg?

Answer (score 1):

Let's say $X$ is the number of cars exceeding the speed limit in 5 minutes.  From the stated conditions,
$$P(X \ge 1) = P(X=0)$$
so
$$1 - P(X = 0) = P(X=0)$$
which implies $P(X=0) = 1/2$.  If we make the assumption that $X$ has a Poisson distribution with rate $\lambda$, then we have 
$P(X=0) = e^{-\lambda} = 1/2$, so $\lambda = \ln 2$ cars per 5 minute period.  Finally,
$$P(X=3) = \frac{1}{3!} \lambda^3 e^{-\lambda} = \frac{(\ln 2)^3}{12}$$

Answer (score 1):

In general, a distribution is considered Poisson if you have some sort of time interval and a probability measure associated with it.

In this case, we have both.

We always let $\lambda$ be the time measure, which is $5$ in this case. More precisely it is $5$ minutes.

We let $X$ be the number of arrivals, or the number of events that take place. In your problem, we let $X$ be the amount of cars exceeding the speed limit, which is $3$ cars.

We have the $P_X(x)=\dfrac{e^{-\lambda}\lambda^x}{x!}$

Finding $P(X=3)=\dfrac{e^{-5}\lambda^3}{3!}$

Comment: The $\lambda$ in the Poisson distribution is the rate (cars per time period), not the time period.  It is incorrect to say that $\lambda = 5$ minutes.  For example, suppose you have 10 cars arriving on average every 5 minutes; that's a different distribution than if you had 1 car arriving every 5 minutes.  The time period alone is not sufficient to determine the distribution.

Comment: So, do you mean you have another option for this?

Comment: @2468 Yes, I have posted a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I would argue, that you most likely looking for the Poisson distribution here.

It is characterized by “expresses the probability of a given number of events occurring in a fixed interval of time or space if these events occur with a known constant rate and independently of the time since the last event”
Your fixed time interval is the five minutes and they don’t say there is a constant rate, but I guess that is the purpose of the last sentence.

As Herb points out, we need to know the mean value (same as the rate) to put a numerical value to the probability.

source: 
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution

Comment: How we can find the average number of cars traveling the road?

Comment: Can we assume that the rate $\lambda =1$ as the probability of a car exceeding the speed limit is the same as of all cars abiding the speed limit?